# NSLocale setPreferredLanguage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nssortdescriptor, nslocale

I seem to be going in circles around this problem and I am heading no where now.

I am trying to force the language of my app (to swedish) as shown below.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sv", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

I have done it in the main method, so that preference is set as soon as the application is launched.

Then when i want to sort an array alphabetically i use `NSSortDescriptor` with selector `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

> NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"iName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
>
> NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];
>
> self.ingredientsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.ingredientsList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]];

But my problem is sorting with my local language does not happen the first time. But if I restart the app, the sorting is according to the language (Swedish). Why doesnt it happen the first time?

What am i doing wrong?

Help/suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the language settings in the first place!

Comment: I want a list in swedish to be sorted alphabetically. (alphabetically in swedish and not in english irrespective of users phone language). what is the right way of doing this then?

Comment: @DarkDust is it wrong to force an application language then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@DarkDust is correct. You should not try to modify the locale itself. That's not under your control, and as you're seeing, it doesn't work very well. Most importantly, if you just want to modify one sort operation, this is a very big hammer to do that.... You could potentially play with the various localization `Info.plist` entries (particularly `CFBundleLocalizations`) to get this to work right, but not just to sort a single list.

What you want to use is `compare:options:range:locale:`, which allows you to pass a specific locale. You can use this method inside of a `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` or `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`.

Alternately, you could use a category to add a custom `swedishCaseInsensitiveCompare:` to `NSString`. You could then use `NSSortDescriptor` as you are currently.

---

Example. `ä` is sorted after `a` in English, but after `z` in Swedish:

```
@interface NSString (SwedishSorting)
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveSwedishCompare:(id)other;
@end

@implementation NSString (SwedishSorting)
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveSwedishCompare:(id)other;
{
  return [self compare:other options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) locale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sv"]];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {
    NSArray *array = [@"Jag är en test av sortering" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *englishSort = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
    NSLog(@"English = %@", englishSort);

    NSArray *swedishSort = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveSwedishCompare:)]]];

    NSLog(@"Swedish = %@", swedishSort);                                                                
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have just one sorting in my entire app and I want that to be sorted in Swedish and not in english.

Comment: Right, the above should achieve that. Modifying the locale impacts many things other than sorting.

Comment: Can you please give me an example.

Comment: When I set my device language to swedish it works perfectly. But if i change my device language to English the sorting is done in English and the swedish characters are placed in the middle.

Comment: `NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"se"]; sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) { return [a compare:b options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, a.length) locale:locale]; }]; [locale release];`

Comment: Added. This is for a command-line app, but it should be obvious how to move it to iOS.